# How to create a notification like button or label?

Tags: android

I need to create icons that have a superscript number onto it. The super-scripted number should be programmable from the code. These icons are used for displaying the pending tasks and completed tasks in my app. How can i achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Check this [page](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/140). There are so many third party libraries available for achieving this.

Comment: Create a layout that does it. RelativeLayout should be the easiest

Answer (score 0):

I did not use a library to do that in one of my projects and I ended up creating my own personal.

This is the layout I was using

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_messages_layout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_button_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_dialog_message"
            android:layout_width="65dip"
            android:layout_height="65dip"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_message_icon" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_badge_notification_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/relative_button_layout"
        android:background="@drawable/badge_count"
        android:text="16"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the `badge_count` drawable is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <corners android:radius="8dp" />
    <solid android:color="#f20000" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dip"
        android:color="#FFF" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="5dp"
        android:left="5dp"
        android:right="5dp"
        android:top="5dp" />
</shape>
```

You can change it to a rectangle, ring, whatever.

Then in the logic of the app, you have to hide or show the `tv_badge_notification_text` whenever you have messages, and set the text with the exact number you have.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code to achieve your functionality,change id of views and images as per your requirement[image]  check the above image and code ;)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-30dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/msg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_162sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_30sdp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_18ssp"
            android:text="5"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_165sdp"
            android:textColor="#000"/>


    </RelativeLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/msg"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/_80sdp"
        android:background="@drawable/contact" />
</RelativeLayout>
```